# Ubuntu consistenly restarts at gui interaction

Tags: gnome, ati, xorg

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Gnome. I recently swapped out my AMD gfx card for an Nvidia card and then back again. In the process i have ended up here - a rebooting system.

I have thus far used `aticonfig --intial` to recreate xorg.conf

I have also tried different fglrx drivers, but to no avail.

Heading into recovery mode and then using failsafeX, gives me an error:

```
Fatal server error: No screens found
```

The failsafe log file repeats the above mentioned erro along with

```
Screens found, but none have a usable confirguration
```

I would love to post more info, but i can't access that system long enough. Please let me know what further info will help. Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

** EDIT: installing drivers from AMD website improved the situation.

Comment: Do you have access to a terminal?

Comment: To access terminal press `Alt+Ctrl+F1`

Comment: Yes i can access a terminal by selecting recovery mode from grub menu and then dropping to root terminal.

Comment: Upgrading the graphics drivers from the AMD website has IMPROVED the situation, but not solved it.